# Pick Values from JSON Object Where Keys in Typescript Type

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I have a the following type:

```
interface User {
  email: string;
  name: string;
}
```

...and the following react component:

```
const MyComponent = <Values extends object>({ values }: { values: Values }) => {
  console.log(values);
  return <div></div>
}
```

Let's say I use `MyComponent` with the `User` interface, and so I'm able to pass `values` to it. The question is: how do I modify the `values` JSON object being passed to pluck out any properties in it that are **not** present in the generic type `Values`? In other words, if I pass the object:

```
{
  email: 'mail@example.org',
  name: 'Some name',
  foo: 'bar'
}
```

I need the `console.log(values)` in the component to log the object without `foo: 'bar'` in it.

Comment: You can't, types don't exist at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Types don't exist at runtime Typescript **compiles** to javascript.